# Raw data spreadsheet

Tags: database, editor, csv, spreadsheet, table

I use little tables that contain mainly text on a daily basis. I currently use LibreOffice Calc to view and edit them, with the Autofilter feature for sorting and filtering. However, spreadsheets are overkill in my case: the startup is slow, I don’t want text formatting, and I don’t want to have to resize columns or rows to see all the content. Moreover, I don’t like how the spreadsheet is already an “infinite” empty table, I’d rather add rows or columns when I need them.

I am looking for a file type and an editor with the following features:

- Easy table edition (add, move and remove columns and rows)
- No visual formatting (no rich text, automatic visual resizing of the table depending on the content)
- Sorting and filtering the table along any row or column
- Handling textual, numeric or boolean data
- Counting functions (eg. proportion of entries that have a given value)
- Adding text outside of the table itself (in the same file)
- Compatible with Windows 10

Additionaly, the following features would be nice:

- Markdown syntax highlighting
- Open-source software

I did some research and found the CSV/TSV format. It’s not too bad, but nothing can be added outside of the table, and it is not well-defined, so many editors have to ask for the separator when opening a file.
A lightweight database editor may do the trick?